# SQL. DELETE Removal under several conditions (SQL. DELETE)

Tags: sql, where-clause, sql-delete

I have data base.
I have to delete strings that meet several conditions: AND, OR
Will delete people who were born from 2001-10-01 to 2010-10-01 and have names of the format XXXan or AnXXX, where X is an arbitrary symbol*

```
DELETE FROM people 
WHERE date> 2001-10-01 AND date < 2010-10-01 AND names LIKE ‘…an’ OR ‘An...’
```

But the second part of the request immediately applies AND to the first type of name, but I need the AND to select one of the two names.

Comment: Use brackets to enclose 2 OR conditions.

Comment: and use [Fieldname] like [value] all Time not just at the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use brackets to group the conditions.

```
DELETE FROM people 
WHERE date> 2001-10-01 AND date < 2010-10-01 AND (names LIKE ‘…an’ OR ‘An...’)
```